# Foreign Key Relations between 2 apps and User model

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have one app in which a model extends the User mode.

```
class ExtendedUser (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    favorite_color = models.CharField(...
    #...
```

I have another app that also has a foreignkey with the user model.

I wanted to know how can I access all the information related to a particular user?

My problem comes when I try to make inverse relationships (I think), here is what I try:

```
>>from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>from firstapp.models import ExtendedUser

>>a = User.objects.get(pk=1)
>>a
<User: username1>
>>b = a.favorite_color
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'favorite_color'
>>c = ExtendedUser.objects.get(pk=1)
>>c
<User: username1>
>>c.favorite_color
<Favorite_color: blue>
```

The problem is when I am on "a" I cannot access the extended model information on the user, such as "favorite_color", and when I am on "c" I cannot access the User model native info such as email or perms.  Is there a way to do this?

And also,

Is there a way where I can pick one user id and see all the fields (from all models and apps) that are related to that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But this isn't "extending the user model" at all. You have a reference to a completely different model, via a ForeignKey. I don't know why you'd expect `favorite_color` to suddenly become an attribute on the User model.

Instead of a ForeignKey (which implies many ExtendedUsers for each User), use a `OneToOneField`. Then you can follow the relationship directly:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
print user.extendeduser.favorite_color
```